# dyamically appended javascript file throws; is it possible to catch?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

In `file2.js` I have:

```
throw new String("oops");
```

In `file1.js` I have:

```
document.head.appendChild(dynamically_created_file_2_script_element);
```

How can I catch the string thrown in `file2.js`?

I have tried:

```
try {
    document.head.appendChild(dynamically_created_file_2_script_element);
}
catch(err) { ... }
```

to no avail. Also, the `onerror` event listener on `dynamically_created_file_1_script_element` is of no use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before appending the script, you can add an [error listener to the window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event).

> The error event is fired on a Window object when a resource failed to load or couldn't be used — for example if a script has an execution error.

Inside the handler, you can check which resource resulted in the error by looking at the `filename` property of the event.

```
window.addEventListener('error', (errorEvent) => {
    if (errorEvent.filename.endsWith('file2.js')) {
        console.log('Saw error from file2.js:')
        console.log(errorEvent.message);
    }
});

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = './file2.js';
```

Note that this can only work if the script is on a live server, and on the same domain. Due to cross-origin restrictions, in other situations, the only info available will be `Script error`.

Comment: I've made some progress but still can't solve my issue (issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74647504/catching-an-error-or-exception-thrown-from-a-dynamically-appended-script-element if you wanna read).