# catching an error or exception thrown from a dynamically appended script element - possible?

Tags: javascript

I want to stop script execution in a dynamically appended script (as in *include_guard*) by throwing an error from the appended file. Then I want to catch this error from the file that did the "appending" (as in "making things clean").

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>pickle</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var de = document.createElement("script");
            de.src = "file.js";
            
            document.head.appendChild(de);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> file.js

```
throw new Error("blabla");
```

How can I catch the error thrown ?

Something like this doesn't catch anything (probably because the appending is happening in a different thread):

```
var de = document.createElement("script");
de.src = "file.js";
try {
    document.head.appendChild(de);
}
catch(e) {
     console.log("got it");
}
```

I also tried setting an error listener to the window object, which *does* receive error notification, but the error is not *caught*.

Reason I want to do that: I wrote a javascript includer that works pretty much like the c/c++ `#include` directive with support for a `#pragma once`-like feature.

If a file is included 2+ times and it was tagged as `once`, I need to stop execution for this file - by throwing or erroring the script from inside the `once()` function.

Note: it *aleady* works. My `once()` function throws a custom `include_guard` object and script execution is halted. If possible, I want to catch that error and print a warning instead, to make things look cleaner (not a life or death situation...).

Comment: "*I want to stop script execution*" - why? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Bergi I wrote a javascript includer with support for a `#once`-like feature. It works just well, I'm trying to catch the error to make it cleaner, and print it as a warning instead (`file.js` was already included... etc...).

Comment: Is this error in the form of an exception? If the exception is constructed properly, this should be sufficient. If you really feel need to do something non-standard, like "print a message", what do you mean by that? Is `console.warn()` or such not sufficient?

Comment: @Ouroborus `console.warn()` is exactly what I want to do. But I need to catch the exception first. I am throwing a custom error object like this: `throw new instance.internal.exceptions.include_guard("message");` --- `instance.internal.exceptions.include_guard` is a function. It is **not** caught in the `try-catch` block above in my post.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't write to the console just before throwing the exception? As in `console.warn(...); throw new ...;`?

Comment: If you're expecting to be able to catch such an exception from outside of `once` but it's not your code or even your `script` element that's calling `once`, you're not going to be able to do that. Best you can do is listen for the `error` event and hope they haven't wrapped `open` in a `try`/`catch`.

Comment: @Ouroborus I could print a warning just before throwing the exception, but the exception must be thrown anyway, to stop script execution :/ And yes it's my code, `once()` is not wrapped in a try-catch block and the exception logs as an error. I guess it's not possible to catch that error, thanks anyway.

Comment: please give an eye here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event ... I honestly had no idea before and didn't try yet but as far as I could see it looks like what you are looking for .. a way to catch any exception thrown anywhere.. I'm not totally sure because I didn't try myself but I read it's like that and with the chance to stop the propagation there. I wonder if such event could be limited to script tags as well. (by the way..) I felt your pain before in the comments :D Good luck with your search!

Comment: @DiegoD I could make some progress with your advice but I can't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to cancel an error by listening to it in `window.onerror` and returning `true` from the handler.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event

Example:

```
window.onerror = function(event, source, lineno, colno, error) {
    if (error instanceof my_custom_error) {
        console.warn(my_custom_error + " was canceled.");
        return true;
    }

    //don't disrupt anything else
    return false;
}
```

In the specific issue of the OP tho, `error` is `null` and the error string in `event` is a generic `"Script error"` message (tested on Chrome), so this method can't be used.

It seems the reason for `error` to be `null` is that the error is thrown from a different file.